# Using GROUP BY clause in arcpy.da.UpdateCursor

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, cursor, grouping

I need to specify a "group by" clause for UpdateCursor arcpy.da. From [here](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/UpdateCursor/018w00000014000000/) I found out that it's possible to do using an optional pair of SQL prefix and postfix. But there are no examples and I'm stuck with the syntaxis problem.

Can you help me?

I've tried various modifications of `"(None, 'GROUP BY "INPUT_FID"')"`, but still can't get it.

Here is the part of the code I'm using:

```
oDSFields = ('INPUT_FID','NEAR_FID','DISTANCE', popTotalField, popBlacksField)

kernel = 0
alpha = 0.005
#, "(None, 'GROUP BY "INPUT_FID"')"
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("outDistanceSorted", oDSFields, "(None, 'GROUP BY "INPUT_FID"')") as cursor:

    for row in cursor:

        kernel = float(math.exp(-0.5*math.pow(row[2]/alpha, 2)))
```

Comment: It looks like you are passing your group by as the where part.  Try this: `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("outDistanceSorted", oDSFields,sql_clause="(None, 'GROUP BY "INPUT_FID"')"`

Comment: for anyone looking for an answer: the way to do this is by including the objectID in the sql clause even though you don't want to show it, it won't work otherwise... sql = [None,"Group BY r_Identity, ObjectID"] see: http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/106209-using-join-by-in-arcpy.da.searchcursor%28%29-what-is-the-right-syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem in a much easier way. ArcGIS has a perfect tool "Summary Statistics" in the "Analysis" toolbox, which is very flexible and was used here as a substitute for SQL

`...SUM(field1)...GROUP BY field2`.

Answer (score 4):

As @NathanW pointed out, you are trying to pass your sql_clause to the where_clause parameter. I've found two posts ([here](http://arcpy.wordpress.com/tag/sql_clause/) and [here](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/77876-Group-By-functionality-of-da.cursors-sql_clause)) that show passing the sql_clause parameter as a tuple (the help also agrees), not a string, so you might want to try the following:

```py
sql = (None, 'GROUP BY "INPUT_FID"')
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor("outDistanceSorted", oDSFields, sql_clause=sql) as cursor:
```

If that doesn't work, your syntax should include some escape characters if you want quotations around `INPUT_FID` (these are a few ways you can do it):

```py
(None, 'GROUP BY \"INPUT_FID\"')
```

or

```py
(None, 'GROUP BY "INPUT_FID"')
```