# How to use GROUP BY with arcpy.da.SearchCursor in file geodatabase?

Tags: python, arcmap, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, sql

```
fc = "C:\Users\AuxS3-4\Documents\ArcGIS/Default.gdb\Malla" 
    fields = ('OBJECTID','Sentido','Carriles','idMalla') 
    sqlclause=(None, "GROUP BY Sentido")
cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(fc, fields,sql_clause=sqlclause)
```

**not working**

> RuntimeError: An invalid SQL statement was used. [SELECT
>   OBJECTID, Sentido, idMalla FROM Malla GROUP BY Sentido

**arcgis 10.1!!!**

Comment: I have tested this and found the same problem at 10.2 with a file geodatabase. I tried with and without enclosing the field name in quotes. The GROUP BY clause is supposed to be supported at 10.1 and up in file geodatabases.

Comment: Looks like another thread on this topic. I was testing locally and also had trouble: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/67810/group-by-clause-in-the-updatecursor-arcpy-da

Answer (score 2):

First, you can't include more fields than those that are being grouped unless the other fields are being used in an aggregation (Sum, Count, Max, Min, etc.). This isn't a limitation of ArcGIS, but of SQL.

In other words, for every value of Sentido, there will be several values for OBJECTID, Carriles and idMalla. How can it group by Sentido and return values for the other fields at the same time?

Secondly, and most important I suppose, this appears to be a bug (in 10.1 at least), or we are all misunderstanding how to use the `sql_clause` parameter of `arcpy.da.SearchCursor`. I've tried several combinations of using a `GROUP BY` clause with a search cursor and nothing will work. It keeps including the ObjectID field even when not specified in the `fields` parameter, which causes an error due to the above.

So, even when you do get your fields formatted properly, I don't think it will work as expected. I recommend contacting ESRI about this.

Comment: It depends on the implementation whether an aggregation function is required, but from my understanding, it should not be required and should simply return an indeterminate (random, or perhaps first) value for other columns in the grouped rows.

Comment: Although I've never encountered a database that supports the behavior you are describing, it is possible. That would be undefined behavior though, and I would never recommend designing any process, code or script around it.

Comment: I just know that MySQL works that way, not sure about others.